# LP warehouse problem with a certain truck capacity

Tags: linear-programming

The problem that I need to solve is almost like the basic LP warehouse problem, where you have n warehouses, each one with a certain amount of a product, and m shops, each one demanding a certain amount of that product. So the goal is to minimize the amount of Km made by the trucks that have to deliver the products from the warehouses to the shops.
This was the easy part, I already identified the constraints and the objective function.
The part that I can't get my head around, is that the truck that delivers the products has a certain capacity, C. Every single truck has the same capacity. I can't tell if that piece of information is really relevant and should be included in some kind of constraint or something. I would really apreciate a hint, cause I've been stuck on this part for a while now and couldn't fine any example of this exact type of problem on the Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of trucs needed can be bounded by

```
numtrucs(i,j)*capacity >= shipment(i,j)
```

Add a term to the objective that minimizes the number of trucs.

Comment: The thing is that I need to minimize the distance traveled by the trucks, not the amount of trucks that I use. There is a certain cost for each Km that the trucks travel and that is what I need to minimize

Comment: Is that not obvious or am I missing something (always possible)?  `numtrucs(i,j)*km(i,j)`

Comment: Yeah that's what i have as the objective function that minimizes the total distance traveled. The thing is i thought that maybe there should be some kind of constraint for the capacity of the trucks as there is for the total products shipped from a warehouse and the total received in a shop. I guess that I've just been overthinking the problem... Anyway, thanks :)